# how to get gridview all rows data when using paging

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with paging (page size 10), which contains Course details. when i am saving gridview data into database it save only 10 record (according to page).
is there any to get all gridview all rows.
e.g. if my gridview contains 25 rows with paging and when i save data into database then all 25 rows data insert into database?
please help...
Here is my code

```
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("row_index");
        dt.Columns.Add("edited_value");
        IList<int?> SeqNos = new List<int?>();


        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvViolationCodes.Rows)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("txtSeqNo");
            Label lblSysid = (Label)gvr.FindControl("lblSysID");
            HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)gvr.FindControl("HiddenField1");
            if (tb.Text != hf.Value)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                SeqNos.Add(Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text));
                dr["row_index"] = lblSysid.Text;
                dr["edited_value"] = tb.Text;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
```

Comment: in which event you are looping through all the rows int he grid view and saving the data ?

Comment: i have button outside gridview to update records of gridview . for that im looping through all the rows

Comment: Check out this Code Project question for help. http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/550721/howplustoplusgetplusgridviewplusallplusrowsplusdat

Comment: i have textbox column in gridview when i click on update button outside of gridview need to update database with changed values in textbox of gridview of all rows

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the data in temporary storage in PageIndexChanging event of GrIdView. On final save send the datatable to Sql Server Procedure or loop through the datatable and save it in database. Follow the steps:

```
 protected void grdView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        fnStoreGridData();
    }
    private void fnStoreGridData()
    {
        DataTable TempDataTable = new DataTable();
        if(Session["Data"]!=null){
            TempDataTable = Session["Data"] as DataTable;
        }
        else{
            TempDataTable.Columns.Add("exCourse", typeof(string)) ;
            TempDataTable.Columns.Add("exUniversityCourse", typeof(string)) ;
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvExportCourse.Rows)
        {
            Label exCourse = (Label)row.FindControl("gvlblCourseName");
            Label exUniversityCourse = (Label)row.FindControl("gvlblUniversityCourseName");
            if (exCourse != null)
            {
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exCourse.Text))
               {
                    TempDataTable.Rows.Add(exCourse.Text, exUniversityCourse.Text);
                    //TempDataTable is your datatable object. Make sure that datatable contains these columns
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

In Final Save:

```
protected void button_Click(object s, EventArg e)
{
    fnStoreGridData(); //Here this will bind the data of current page
    DataTable TempDataTable = new DataTable();
    if(Session["Data"]!=null){
        TempDataTable = Session["Data"] as DataTable;
    }
    //Now loop through datatable and store the values
    foreach(DataRow in TempDataTable.Rows)
    {
        CourseInformation course = new CourseInformation();
        course.AddCourseMaster(dr["exCourse"].ToString(), dr["exUniversityCourse"].ToString());
    }
    label1.Text = "Course saved successfully.";
}
```